# Could not turn wifi on

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I just installed 9 and 10 version of CyanogenMod on my Xperia mini pro (downloaded from http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=mango), but I could not turn the wi-fi on. Version 9 is stable version. What is wrong?

Does the method of ROM installing have any influence on the issue?

Comment: Might be compatibility issues with the radio image version. Or a known bug in CM. The official CM wiki [does not list the mini pro](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Devices#vendor=%22Sony%22;) -- so it is most likely a port from another device, which might cause some issues. You need to check the documentation where you got the images from (XDA?).